# Testing the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

We are nearing finish of the web application done in RoR (it is Social website). I am not RoR person, I am just JS/Jquery side.

All of us do not have much experience with big applications, and this is the first one we have ever done (not counting small apps). It look and feels ok, but except normal testing done by humans we have not used another testing available.

What can you recommend me to do? What programs are out there that I can use to stress the application and create scenarios? Some application that will crawl all around the place and find problems/vulnerabilities that we have not yet detected?

I am walking blind here, so any help is kindly appreciated.

:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Functionality Testing*

Many automated browsers such as [SeleniumHQ](http://seleniumhq.org/) can perform the tests. If you feel it is too complicated you can write your own script with [greasemonkey / tempermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) since you have knowledge in js and jQuery.

*Performance and stability testing*

If you expect the number of user is large, it is worth to do stress test with [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) although it is a bit complicated. You can use it to record test cases and replay it with in large volume. Performance bottleneck can be identified during stress test, and server can be tweak to improve stability.

*Security testing*

It is a long topic about finding vulnerabilities so you would better ask some expert in IT security. In short [Nessus](http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus) can do basic screening, however, it could produce false negative when it is not configured by expert.

Comment: An alternative to Nessus is w3af, which is FOSS.